# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
    at Object.success ((index):301)
    at fire (jquery-1.8.2.js:988)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.8.2.js:1096)
    at done (jquery-1.8.2.js:7802)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.8.2.js:8514)
```

[image]

Comment: Your Jquery must be loaded before you call any object with "$".

Answer (score 2):

your js file should be in order as such

1. Jquery file
2. Jquery datatable file
3. the script tag where you initialize datatable

   $(document).ready( function () {
       $('#myTable').DataTable();
   } );

order of your script tags

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

2nd

```
<script src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

you have written datatable first then jquery which is wrong

Comment: Thank you Yash for your response .i added as you said order ,but still iam getting dataTable is not a function error .

Comment: success: (function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        myData = data;
                        var table = jQuery("#tbprojectmanager").dataTable({
                            "paging": true,
                            "searching": true,
                            "ordering": true
                        }); //close DataTable

Comment: i need code of your html and js where you initiated your datatable and add refrence to js files

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: success: (function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        myData = data;


                        var table = jQuery("#tbprojectmanager").dataTable({
                            "paging": true,
                            "searching": true,
                            "ordering": true


                        }); //close DataTable

Comment: check answer again, edited with script tags sequence

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. By changing the position of jQuery library links and jQuery DataTable links it solved.

There could be multiple reasons for this error.

- jQuery DataTables library is missing.
- jQuery library is loaded after jQuery DataTables.
- Multiple versions of jQuery library is loaded.

**Include only one version of jQuery library version before jQuery DataTables.**