# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function in PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have some code to perform CRUD operation in MYSQLI and PHP. But when I try to convert the HTML table to Datatable am getting error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

When I checked on google, I found this stack answer [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456151/uncaught-typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function-in-jquery)

> your js file should be in order as such
>
> Jquery file
>
> Jquery datatable file
>
> the script tag where you initialize datatable

```
$(document).ready( function () { $('#myTable').DataTable(); } );
```

i tried the same way , but am getting the same error , Can anyone please check on to it

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

I just tried keeping jquery first , but still am getting that error

Comment: Remove the 2nd jquery script src

Comment: You also have added `datatables.bootstrap.min.js`, but you haven't included Bootstrap itself. If there's a dependency there, you'll get errors.

Comment: Check the [tag:datatables] [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) - there's a ready made snippet in the correct order.  Doesn't include bootstrap though.  Include the (missing) bootstrap js before dataTables.bootstrap.min

Comment: @freedomn-m, removed it but still not workng

Comment: added as in the "https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info" , but it's still not working @freedomn-m

Comment: Can you recreate it in a snippet here or in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Another troubleshooting step is to remove all your existing resources and then build a fresh set from the [DataTables download page](https://datatables.net/download/index).